# aws s3 and cloudfront process cookie

Tags: express, amazon-s3, cookies, amazon-cloudfront

I have a problem about s3 and cloudfront process cookie.

My client web is set on s3 with cloudfront, and server is set on beanstalk(node.js+express).

I need to send a jwt token from server to client through 'cookie' (code: res.cookie(token)). 
It all woks on local. But after I deploy on aws, I cannot get any cookie from server. I find that aws doc says

> "Amazon S3 and some HTTP servers don’t process cookies. Don’t
>   configure CloudFront to forward cookies to an origin that doesn’t
>   process cookies, or you’ll adversely affect cacheability and,
>   therefore, performance."

Is there any possible solution with revising cloudfront cookies setting? or I need to change my server code that not send token with cookies?

Comment: This might help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63887518/#70828064