# How do I ensure CloudFront returns cookies from my Elastic Beanstalk REST API application

Tags: cookies, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront

I have a Java Spring Boot application for a REST API deployed in AWS Elastic Beanstalk. It is HTTP not HTTPS.

Let's call it `http://foobar.elasticbeanstalk.com/api`.

I am using a AWS CloudFront distribution to terminate HTTPS, *but not to cache anything* (I have set my Cache Policy to "Managed-CachingDisabled".

Let's call it `https://dfoobar123.cloudfront.net`.

There are some APIs that require the client to be "logged in". There is one call, `/login` which results in a ACCESS_TOKEN being returned in the response cookie. Subsequent calls have to include that access token to be successful.

The app directly is all OK. When I go to http://foobar.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/login (Elastic Beanstalk app directly), the server logs me in and returns the cookie.

But, when I go to the CloudFrontDistribution, https://dfoobar123.cloudfront.net/api/login, I can see the server authenticating me, but I do not get the cookie back in the response headers.

What setting do I need to turn on in CloudFront to enable this?

Comment: Just to check: are you inspecting the response headers and you don't see the set-cookie, or you inspect the next request and see that you are still unauthenticated?

Comment: @TamásSallai. Correct. I am inspecting the response coming from CloudFront and it has no Set-Cookie header. Theresponse for the same request, if coming from the EB instance, does have the Set-Cookie header in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to forward cookies in the cache behavior. Without it, CloudFront removes the Set-Cookie header from the response.

Here's the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Cookies.html):

> You can configure each cache behavior to do one of the following:

...

> Don’t forward cookies to your origin – CloudFront doesn’t cache your objects based on cookie sent by the viewer. In addition, CloudFront removes cookies before forwarding requests to your origin, and removes Set-Cookie headers from responses before returning responses to your viewers.

Comment: Thanks @TamásSallai, I do not see these options in my cache behaviour. (I had seen this documentation)

Comment: You might need to select Legacy cache settings to see this

Comment: I found it, @TamásSallai. I had to go and edit the Caching policies under Behaviours, and added a custom policy which seems to work so far

Answer (score 11):

### Cookies are blocked *by default*

Making them work requires two changes, in the behavior settings:

1. Allowing cookies to pass through (on the request)
2. Letting the `Set-Cookie` header come back (with the response)

#### Where to change cookie settings...

[image: cloudfront ui for cookies]

*Confused? If so, then...*

#### Here's the step-by-step process...

In your CloudFront distribution:

1. Go to the **Behaviors** tab
2. Select the behavior and click **Edit**
3. Find the **Cache key and origin requests** section
4. Under **Origin request policy** click on **Create policy**
5. Fill in the **Name**, and then scroll to the bottom and change **Cookies** from **None** to **All** (or **Include Specified Cookes**, if you want to whitelist)
6. Hit **Create** to save the new policy
7. Switch back to the original tab (with the **Edit behavior** page)
8. Find the **Cache key and origin requests** section again
9. Under **Response headers policy**, tap on **Create policy**
10. Fill in the **Name**, and then Scroll to the bottom
11. Under **Custom headers**, tap the **Add header** button
12. In the **Name** field put `Set-Cookie`
13. Leave **Value** empty, and **Origin override** should stay unchecked
14. Hit the **Create button**
15. Go back to the **Edit behavior** page, hit the refresh buttons, so you can pick those two new policies
16. Hit **Save Changes** and give it a few minutes to deploy

Comment: THANK YOU LORD AND SAVIOR MR TWO-BIT-FOOL!!!! I LOVE YOU

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful! For my setup using nextjs and next-auth with email login, I also had to select "Query strings - All" for the origin request policy for it to work all the way.